# PowerShell Active Directory list all Multi-Valued attributes

Tags: powershell, active-directory

not sure if I'm chaing the wild goose here but as per subject I'd need to get a list of AD attributes, for the user ObjectClass, that are multie valued.

For example the proxyAddresses exchange specific attribute is multi valued where extensionAttribute* only accept a single string.

We use a heavily customized schema and while I could go through each attribute documentation I'd rather get a list of aforementioned attributes via PowerShell.

I've tried using ldp.exe but could not achive desired results and was wondering if there is a way to do this via PowerShell or .Net managed code.

Thanks in advance for any help/pointer.

Comment: Ok apparently my quesiton is not clear as we're talking about two different things or I cannot figure out how your example relate to my original question.

Don't get me wrong I highly appreciate your help but simply is not what I'm looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have to query the Schema part of the directory and look for *objectClass* `attributeSchema` and *attribute* `isSingleValued` (FALSE). The part of the distinguichName wichh is invariant is : `CN=Schema,CN=Configuration`.

try first with CSV :

```
csvde -f MultivaluedAttributes.csv -d CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MySubdomain,DC=MyDomain,DC=com -r "(&(objectclass=attributeSchema)(isSingleValued=FALSE))" -l lDAPDisplayName
```

Here is the powershell code.

```
# LDAPSchemaQuery.PS1
try
{
  $dn = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry ("LDAP://179.22.21.01/CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=MyDomain,DC=MyExt","MyUser", 'MyPassword')
  # Query into the Schema
  # csvde -f MultivaluedAttributes.csv -d CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=office,DC=coyotesystems,DC=com -r "(&(objectclass=attributeSchema)(isSingleValued=FALSE))" -l lDAPDisplayName
  $Rech = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dn)
  #$Rech.filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(mail=*)(!(UserAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))"
  $Rech.filter = "(&(objectclass=attributeSchema)(isSingleValued=FALSE))"
  $Rech.SearchScope = "subtree"
  $dumy=$Rech.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lDAPDisplayName")

  $adAttributes = $Rech.findall()
  foreach ($adAttribute in $adAttributes) 
  {
    $multivaluedAttribute =  try{$adAttribute.Properties["lDAPDisplayName"]}catch{""}
    $multivaluedAttribute
  }
}
catch
{
  Write-Verbose "LDAPSchemaQuery : PB with $($adAttribute.Path)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks but maybe my question was not clear, I'm trying to report on all attributes defined as multi valued at the Schema level, not report on existing attributes and/or their values.

Comment: So, same player shoot again ... I try to right the PowerShell code.

Comment: Alas not returning any value anyhow it put on track for tying to build an ldapfilter via a GUI app but still no dice. Good news is in the meantime I've found an attribute to use for my need yet I will continue pursuing this as I think it would be handy to have an easy way to get this kind of information

Comment: The two ways works fine for me, be carefull to respect the DN path, you can use Apache Directory Studio in order to verify that.

Comment: Oh thanks for the hint to Apache Directory studio, I did not know the tool... and silly me I ended up writing a tool suited to my needs (now I REALLY feel silly). As per the DN.... I was using my production domain one in my lab DC so silly x 2 :)

Working as inteded I need to filter out users only attributes but that's the say part THANKS A LOT!